# Android - Drawables messed up after every single app update

Tags: android, proguard, drawable

I have an app published on the play store and I am facing an annoying problem both for me and my users.

I am storing a list of Object as a JSON String like this:

```
val obj = JSONObject()
    try {
        ...
        obj.put("image", image)
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        Log.d("JSONException: ", e.message)
    }
```

where `image: Int` stores the value of `R.drawable.image`

The problem is that every time I release an update for my app this image gets replaced with another drawable (not always the same one) from the `/res/` folder.

I suspect it has something to do with proguard's code shrinking, since I have both:

```
minifyEnabled true
shrinkResources true
```

How can I fix the problem?

If possible I would avoid not to shrink the images, since I have a fair amount of them and it would increase the download size of the app.

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot rely on the resource numbers to stay the same across builds. You will need to use another identifier to make persistent and then do a mapping to resource number in your app.

For example you could use an array that contains the resource numbers and you persist the index of a certain drawable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, would the array be the best practice to keep track uniquely of the images?

Comment: That depends a bit on your program and how many images there are. For example if there are several groups of images you may consider to use one array per group. If you have a string as identifier you may consider to use a hash table, ...

Comment: Store the images in a hashmap as your JSON value as key and drawable Id as value for the key...and then fetch your image value as JSON and match this in hashmap and get the drawable as value and set to imageview.

Answer (score 1):

From Google docs: "When your application is compiled, aapt generates the R class, which contains resource IDs for all the resources in your res/ directory. For each type of resource, there is an R subclass (for example, R.drawable for all drawable resources), and for each resource of that type, there is a static integer (for example, R.drawable.icon). This integer is the resource ID that you can use to retrieve your resource." so when you build the APK the ResourceID could change without any expectation...
You can use its Filename and get the ID in runtime using "getResources().getIdentifier(...)"